# Angular 4 web application show verbose warning

Tags: angular, performance, angular-material

I searched a lot but never find any solution to get rid off.My problem is I am using angular material in my web application that build using angular 4 and typescript.Its badly slow down the performance then I find there is lot of function call in console.Any help really appreciated.

One solution that discussed in different forum is make event Emitter by default passive:true.but this is not helpful for me.
[screen shot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teV1P.png)

Comment: Are you using the newest material version? As per this pull request: https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/8719 this was fixed in 5.0.2

Comment: bundle of thanks. its work for me.